# SQL Rearrange row order

Tags: sql, t-sql

Problem:
A row in my_table contains

```
1
2
3
3
4
4
4
```

I want to rearrange the row order to the following

```
4
4
4    
1
3
3
2
```

Is there any way I can perform this?

I have not written any code so far. ( I do not know how to begin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` - it's much cleaner and easier to read.

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN YourColumn = 4 then 0
              WHEN YourColumn = 2 then 1
              ELSE 2 END, yourcolumn
```

It's also a bad idea to change the order of the rows since there is actually no inherent order in SQL - it's all in the presentation layer, so use `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT`s to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2):

as Adam Wenger said,

or if you wanted, it could be done in your table, meaning your sql statement can remain as a basic select * from table order by newcolumn*

*see below

```
add a new column
update each row set column=1 where original_column=4
update each row set column=2 where original_column=2
update each row set column=3 where original_column=1
update each row set column=4 where original_column=3
```

and then order by this new column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT yourColumn
FROM
(
   SELECT yourColumn
      , CASE yourColumn
           WHEN 4 THEN 1
           WHEN 1 THEN 2
           WHEN 3 THEN 3
           WHEN 2 THEN 4
        END AS SortColumn
   FROM yourTable
) AS t
ORDER BY t.SortColumn ASC
```

This will sort 4, 1, 3, 2

Comment: Nice.  But wouldn't you also need to trap for the 2 (in the CASE) as well?

Comment: it gives me the following error: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

Comment: Sort asc isn't going to word as you see 2 is the last value which is desc from 3.

Comment: @Maess I didn't read the question well initially. I have fixed the order in the case to reflect the OP request.

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup table with the original value and the corresponding sort order:

```
SortLookupTable:
OriginalValue, SortOrder
1,             2
2,             4
3,             3
4,             1
```

Then join the table to your original table

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
    MyTable T
    INNER JOIN SortLookupTable S
        ON T.Value = S.OriginalValue
ORDER BY
    S.SortOrder;
```